# How to test Android wear app without actual watch?

Tags: android, wear-os, build.gradle

For developing and testing purpose, I have separately installed the mobile and wear apk-s on the android phone and the watch emulator respectively and can connect between them. I have built the project into one single apk as per the instructions. But, how do I ensure if this bundled apk is working or not and if the wear apk is pushed onto the watch or not? I do not have an actual watch, I'm having to make do with the emulator.

Additionally, when I want to update my app, do I have to update the version name and number for both watch and mobile or only one in build.gradle? Google has made this very confusing, they should have kept the phone and watch separate.

Answer (score 0):

From personal experience, an actual phone will properly push a wearable app to a wearable emulator (my wearable emulator had Mini Launcher running on it).

As for your second question, I'm not sure. However, you should be able to check this on your own now knowing that a phone will push to the emulator.

Comment: Woah! How did you manage to install a launcher on the emulator? I thought we couldnt do that! Also, how do I make the wear apk be pushed onto the emulator from the phone? Currently I'm just uploading both via IDE itself while running. Thanks.

Comment: Wear Mini Launcher isn't a true launcher, but it slightly behaves as one. Look it up: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.npi.wearminilauncher. It's just a normal apk. Just sync the phone and the wearable emulator and you should be good to go.